# Visual C++ copy char array into char array

Tags: c++, arrays

Need help with copying array object to a temp array object using a for loop (see code + comments below)..... Thanks in advance!!!!

```
    int counter;
    char buffer[] = "this is what i want 0 ignore the rest after the zero"; //
    char command[sizeof(buffer)];

    for ( counter = 0; counter < sizeof(buffer); counter++ ){
        if ( buffer[counter] == '0' ){      
            break; // Exit loop (Should Exit)
        }
        command[counter] = buffer[counter]; // Copy array object into new array
        printf("%c",command[counter]);
    }
    printf("\n",NULL);
    printf("%s\n",command); // However when I print it contains the whole array this shouldnt be is should only contain "this is what i want "
```

Comment: that code is C - not c++

Comment: Verify that both zeros are a zero, not an uppercase 'O'. Also, ensure that you terminate the command[] buffer with a null character -- '\0'. Also, the behavior would occur if you accidentally compared ==0, or =='\0'.

Comment: @Seth If something is valid, doesn't mean it should be used. The above is an example how a c++ program shouldn't look like.

Comment: @VJo just because in your opinion it shouldn't be used doesn't mean it isn't C++. It works fine in my C++ compiler, therefore it is C++. It just happens to also be valid C code. You may make similar arguments against the ternary operator and macros. But they're C++ too.

Comment: @Seth The thing that it compiles on your compiler doesn't prove anything. Why against ternary operator and macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ideone.com/haCBP

Your code is working fine:

> output:
>   this is what i want
>   this is what i want

Edit: That being said, you need to initialize your output buffer:

```
char command[sizeof(buffer)]={}; // now the string will be null-termiated
                                 // no matter where the copy ends
```

Comment: *sigh* Sucks when you can't be sure code is wrong when people say it's wrong.

Comment: Using Visual C++ it doesn't print that way :( however after terminating command[counter] = 0 it works

Comment: That's why I added my edit. If you initialize your buffer (like you should in most cases) you won't need the termination.

Comment: @Blindy: the code is not correct as given in the question. zero-filling the buffer is an effective but wasteful way of covering up the bug in the code (and *not* something you should do in most cases, or anything like it).

Answer (score 5):

Strings are terminated by a `'\0'` character

So simply add after the for loop

```
command[counter]=0;
```

(when you exit the for loop the value of `counter` will be "pointing" at the last character's place in the `command` variable)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit easier way to do the job:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%[^0]", command);
```

This copies the right data and assures it's properly terminated, all in one (reasonably) simple operation.

Note, that in C++ you probably want to use `std::string` instead of NUL-terminated arrays of char for situations like this though.

Comment: `sizeof(buffer)` can be determined at compile-time, and thus is a perfectly valid size for the `command` array, even in C++.

Comment: @Karl: Oops, you're entirely correct. I apologize for the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
counter = 0;
while (buffer[counter] != '0'){
command[counter] = buffer[counter];
counter ++;
}
```

try something like this...but add control to make sure you do not excide the buffer/command dimension!